# Person or group column type won't allow manually typing name

Tags: document-library, column

I have a document that was created by someone that left the company so his name no longer appears in the pick list. (I assume this is fed from Active Directory).  Is there a way to enter a name that is not on the pick list?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of this people picker field? If you can explain more?

Comment: We are creating a knowledge base and uploading content.  The issue is some valuable content has been created by people that have left the company and they won't appear on the pick list because they've been removed from Active Directory.

Comment: If the user is removed from active directory then you cannot add this user in people picker field. however you can use single line of text field to the names who has created the document(consider the affects of using free text - like spelling mistakes in name).

Comment: Also, is there something like number of peoples are uploading and managing the content in list are fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot.

When you type the first three characters of a user name, group name, or claim (such as an e-mail address) into the text box, People Picker automatically searches for results that match the first three typed characters from the source you have configured. So if the name you have typed is not in your source(AD or other source), then you cant have that value in the people picker. It is by design.

Comment: Any suggestions?  Should I simply use Single Line Text Box column type and enter the name manually?

Comment: As suggested by @Ganesh, using single line of text to hold the user name will be good, If you know the users who have exited the company, then you can have their names in a choice field and use, so that there wont be any mismatch in the names.